# Entity Framework: Unable to call .OrderBy on calculated field IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am currently struggling to figure out how I can order a query by a field that only has a getter. I have an `IQueryable` being built as follows:

```
var referrals = db.Referrals
                        .Include(x => x.Doctor)
                        .Include(x => x.OfficeLocation)
                        .Where(x => (vm.OfficeLocationSelection == -1 ? true : x.OfficeLocationId == vm.OfficeLocationSelection) &&
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchTerm) ? true : x.Doctor.Name.ToLower().Contains(vm.SearchTerm.ToLower()))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Doctor)
                        .Select(x => new ReferralGridRowViewModel
                        {
                            DoctorName = x.Key.Name,
                            January = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 1 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            February = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 2 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            March = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 3 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            April = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 4 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            May = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 5 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            June = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 6 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            July = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 7 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            August = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 8 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            September = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 9 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            October = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 10 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            November = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 11 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                            December = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 12 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count()
                        });
```

and `ReferralGridRowViewModel` looks as follows (notice the `YearToDate` property):

```
public class ReferralGridRowViewModel
    {
        public string DoctorName { get; set; }

        public int January { get; set; }

        public int February { get; set; }

        public int March { get; set; }

        public int April { get; set; }

        public int May { get; set; }

        public int June { get; set; }

        public int July { get; set; }

        public int August { get; set; }

        public int September { get; set; }

        public int October { get; set; }

        public int November { get; set; }

        public int December { get; set; }

        public int YearToDate {
            get {
                return (January + February + March + April + May + June + July + August + September + October + November + December);
            }
        }
    }
```

when I try to call the following:

`referrals = referrals.OrderByDescending(x => x.YearToDate);`

then I receive the following exception:

> The specified type member 'YearToDate' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

when the query is actually executed on this line:

`referralRows = referrals.Skip(vm.Skip).Take(vm.PageSize).ToList();`

How can I overcome this in a performant manner? I'd rather not add a column to the DB for YearToDate since it would be redundant and I can't `.ToList` everything beforehand and then sort since there are millions of records in teh db and that would be a substantial performance hit

Comment: [Computed Properties and Entity Framework](https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort by `YearToDate` records by checking the grouping for doctorid and year before selecting the actual `ReferralGridRowViewModel` out as follows:

```
                    var referralsGrouping = db.Referrals
                        .Include(x => x.Doctor)
                        .Include(x => x.OfficeLocation)
                        .Where(x => (vm.OfficeLocationSelection == -1 ? true : x.OfficeLocationId == vm.OfficeLocationSelection) &&
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchTerm) ? true : x.Doctor.Name.ToLower().Contains(vm.SearchTerm.ToLower()))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Doctor);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SortColumn))
                    {
                        if (vm.SortColumn == "YearToDate")
                        {
                            if (vm.SortDirection == SortDirectionType.Descending)
                            {
                                referralsGrouping = referralsGrouping.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                referralsGrouping = referralsGrouping.OrderBy(x => x.Count(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var referrals = referralsGrouping
                    .Select(x => new ReferralGridRowViewModel
                    {
                        DoctorName = x.Key.Name,
                        January = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 1 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        February = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 2 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        March = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 3 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        April = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 4 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        May = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 5 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        June = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 6 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        July = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 7 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        August = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 8 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        September = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 9 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        October = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 10 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        November = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 11 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count(),
                        December = x.Where(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Month == 12 && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count()
                    });

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SortColumn))
                {
                    if (vm.SortColumn == "DoctorName")
                    {
                        if (vm.SortDirection == SortDirectionType.Descending)
                        {
                            referrals = referrals.OrderByDescending(x => x.DoctorName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            referrals = referrals.OrderBy(x => x.DoctorName);
                        }
                    }
                    //other vm sort columns
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just add the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...

public class ReferralGridRowViewModel
{
    ...

    [NotMapped]
    public int YearToDate {
    get {
      return (January + February + March + April + May + June + July + August + September + October + November + December);
    }
  }
}
```

It indicates to the EF to ignore the property on the db side. See the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: this doesn't solve my issue. This column does not exist in the database- only in the dto im selecting in my query and EF wont let me order on this column because it doesnt exist in teh db

Comment: @GregH Yeah, I reread your question and noticed that I skipped the part about being unable to sort on the application side, sorry. If that's the case, the only option I see is to do it in a fashion similar to this: 
`...GroupBy(x => x.Doctor)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count(y => y.DoctorId == x.Key.Id && y.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))
.Select(x => new ReferralGridRowViewModel({...});` although I can't say for sure off the top of my head that EF will be able to translate that to SQL in which case it once again will be performed on the application side which is a no-no for you.

Comment: try add [NotMapped] and replace your setter by `{ get; set; }` and add `YearToDate = x.Count()` to `Select`